# vue js 2 : how to communicate between store and a component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am a beginner with vue js.
i m trying to handle errors from component and display it on other component.

Apparently handling work becase i can see data in my store 
With a props to my component (error.vue), it handle it in the data variable.
But after that it can t display it on my vue .
Why ?

Here is my code :

My store is :

```
var store = new Vuex.Store(
{
  state: { 
     errors:{}
  },
  mutations: {
     setErrors(state, error) {
            for(var err in error) {
               state.errors[err] = error[err]
            }
        }
  }
})
```

my vue where i put my error component:

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
<div class="container">
                <error_handling></error_handling>
                <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Error from './components/Error.vue'
    import store from './store';
    export default {
        components: {
            'error_handling': Error
        },
        data() {
            return {
                erreurs: store.state.errors
            }
        }


    }
</script>
```

my error vue :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {{errors_handling}}
            <!--<li v-for="error in errors_handling">{{ error }}</li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['errors_hand'],
        data() {
            return {
                errors_handling: this.errors_hand
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: use getters to get the state in you component

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh with getters or without, not committing a mutation the state will remain unchanged

Comment: You should read the [vuex documentation core concepts](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/core-concepts.html) and then take a look at some official examples here: [github repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples). Hint: You need getters and actions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code.

1. You are getting a state of "errors"
2. You are not committing a mutation
3. By not committing a mutation, you are not changing a state

Docs: [Vuex Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Store.js

```
var store = new Vuex.Store(
{
  state: { 
     errors:{}
  },
  mutations: {   // Change the state object
     setErrors(state, error) {
            for(var err in error) {
               state.errors[err] = error[err]
            }
        }
  },
   getters:{
             // getters gets the current object of state
             GetErrors(state)  //by default getters get state as first paramater
          {
                return state.errors;
          }
       },

})
```

Error Component

```
<script>
      export default {
         computed:{
              errors_handling(){
                 return this.$store.getters.GetErrors;
               }  
         },
        methods:{
            //commit your mutation or dispatch when using action
              ChangeState(error){  
                  this.$store.commiit('setErrors',error);
               }
           }
      }
</script>
```

But you  must use `actions` to run it asyncronously

Comment: I answered you below? It s still not working , indeed i have this error now :
 Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined" :( 
do you know why?

Comment: @thomaspoidevin you are importing mapGetters, but you are not using it anywhere. I suggest you go back to basics of Vuex, to fully understand how you can manipulate the states

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bus to pass errors from wherever they occur to the error component.  This way the error component need not interact with your store or any other component directly, and can manage its own internal state easily.  You also would not need to include the error component in any other component.

This example assumes that you are wanting only a single Error Component instance in your UI.  I would put the error component instance in your main App template and have it show or hide itself based on whether it has any non-handled errors.

To declare a simple bus...

```
in file errorBus.js

import Vue from 'vue'

const errorBus = new Vue();

export default {
    errorBus
}
```

Wherever an error occurs that you want to pass to the error component, use...

```
import errorBus from './errorBus.js'

errorBus.errorBus.$emit("notifyError", { msg: 'An error has occurred'});
```

In the error component...

```
import errorBus from './errorBus.js'

and within the component definition...    

    created: function() {
        errorBus.errorBus.$on("notifyError", function(error) {this.addError(error)};
    },
    data () {
      return {
          errors: []
      };
   },
   methods: {
       addError: function(error) {
           this.errors.push(error);
       }
   }
```

With this mechanism in place, you could easily handle different errors in different ways by passing additional information in the error object - for example, you could add {handling: "toast", priority: 0} which would cause the error component to immediately toast the error.

If you use this to toast, consider having the errors remain for later viewing after the error is toasted - I have always wanted something like an error drawer that I could open *at my leisure* instead of having to handle a toast immediately before it disappears.